# Android SDK manager error Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 503

Tags: android, http

I am not able to install anything from SDK manager. I have tried both checking and unchecking the checkbox at tools->options force https:// but it gives Download interrupted: Unexpected HTTP Status 503 at logcat. What might be the problem? My internet connection is ok for both http and https protocol.

[image: SDK manager log:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 503 HTTP status code indicates the service is temporarily unavailable. As per the [W3C's HTTP status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

I recommend waiting a bit then trying again.